# Unliking tweet with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use a small script I've written to un-favourite tweets. It's failing for no clear reason, saying the tweet can't be found. Normally when this doesn't work it's because the tweet has since been deleted, e.g.:

```
[{u'message': u'No status found with that ID.', u'code': 144}]
```

However, if you look for the tweet in question (e.g. 987330131013308418), you'll see it hasn't been deleted -- https://twitter.com/Brownstoner/status/987330131013308418

My code uses the tweepy api as follows:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweet_id = 987330131013308418

api.destroy_favorite(tweet_id)
```

...Where I have tried tweet_id as an integer (987330131013308418) or string ('987330131013308418') ... but fails either way.

Meanwhile, if I like/favourite the tweet using the following (and an integer) it works fine:

```
api.create_favorite(tweet_id)
```

So what gives?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to favorite a tweet already favorited, you get the error :

```
[{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
```

If you try to un-favorite a tweet that you have not favorited, you get the error :

```
[{'code': 144, 'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]
```

So avoid to un-favorite twice : check before if the tweet is favorite, or catch error and pass.

Comment: Thought this had solved the problem but it hasn't... tweet is definitely a favourite and won't unfavorite.

Comment: It is categorically failing whether integer or string... and the tweets are favourites already (also favourited thru api, but all checked in browser etc etc.).

Comment: Somehow managed to get it working by starting and re-writing from scratch... no idea what was stopping it from working previously, but your suggestion helped so marking it correct :)